# JUnit5 assertion counting in tests

Tags: junit, assertion, junit5

Is there a way to determine the count of assertions called in tests? I am using  the [JUnit 5 Platform Launcher](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api) and can count PASSes, FAILs in each Test Identifier, but cannot count assertions. This is important in results analytics and reporting since not every test is of the same "density," not by a long shot.

I can provide a wrapper around each assert that increments a count or store a hard-coded sum in a test annotation, but the former introduces a contract that must be upheld just for a simple hack in JUnit 5 or can be ignored and the latter involves a lot of manual counting. Appreciated.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
...
int index = 0;
while (index < testValueCount){
    assertTrue(testValue[index]>0);               // Want to capture testValueCount assertions here, not 1 (or none)
    ++index;
}
```

Comment: How the number of assertion could be helpful ? Generally we focus on both the coverage of the tested code and what we actually assert.

Comment: I'm graphing test coverage and there are two tests which took much more effort to implement and provide more coverage. Most tests perform 4 assertions in a 'scenario,' but these perform calculations (assertions) on what they can in loops. The former usually loops over 100,000 data records, the latter 1 record, but performs 60 assertions. Think these should show in the graph somehow, but pass/fail count is a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is unfortunately not possible.

Neither the JUnit Platform nor JUnit Jupiter provides a way to track the number of assertions performed.

If you truly need such a feature, you will either need to wrap assertion invocations on your own or find an assertion framework that supports invocation tracking.

Comment: This lack of a feature is probably intentional and I've been looking into extending  org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions, but the method signatures will vary a bit since I can't override a static method. Then the test framework could instantiate what was extended, and store the counts it tracks in the results. Going to revisit this in a bit with a clearer  head and will mark yours as the answer most likely.

Comment: As one of the designers of JUnit 5, I can confirm that it is intentional. ;-)

Comment: @SamBrannen could you also share the intention behind it?

Comment: @martin, the `Assertions` API in JUnit Jupiter is a simplistic assertion library. It is not tied into the extension model for JUnit Jupiter. Thus, developers are free to choose any assertion library they wish (e.g., AssertJ, Hamcrest, Truth, etc.).

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call the Jupiter Assertions API simplistic. Personally, I switched back from AssertJ to the JUnit API after the improvements made between JUnit 4 and 5.

Comment: I get the intent but on the other hand, why not provide this functionality for the JUnit API first? Other assertion frameworks might follow (or not). It feels a bit odd to restrict the functionality of JUnit based on compatibility with other assertion frameworks. I'm sure assertion counting could be added as an optional feature without breaking any other integrations (e.g., AssertJ, Hamcrest etc. assertions would just be ignored).

Comment: Feel free to open a ticket in the JUnit 5 GitHub issue tracker to start a discussion.